# Função Ajax se repete na página dependendo do número de resultados retornados da consulta, o que pode ser?

Tags: javascript, ajax, aplicação-web, grails

Bom dia o/

Estou trabalhando em um projeto Grails que utiliza JavaScript para realizar a busca (tanto por categoria e por texto) e paginação de itens. Porém, depois de algumas buscas por categoria, a aplicação fica mais lenta. No console do javascript indica que, a cada busca por categoria, a função ajax responsável por atualizar a exibição de itens é chamada diversas vezes. Alguém já passou por isso ou tem alguma ideia da razão porque acontece? O código das funções envolvidas está abaixo.

Função no controle Grails

```
def searchMyGames() {
    def model = [:]
    User user = session.user
    model.myGroups = Group.findAllByOwner(user)
    model.groupsIAdmin = UserGroup.findAllByUserAndAdmin(user,true).group
    def threshold = THRESHOLD
    def maxInstances = 0
    params.order = "desc"
    params.sort = "id"
    params.max = params.max ? Integer.valueOf(params.max) : threshold
    params.offset = params.offset ? Integer.valueOf(params.offset) : 0
    model.max = params.max
    model.threshold = threshold
    log.debug("category: " + params.category)
    def myExportedResourcesList = null
    if(params.category.equals("-1")){
        // exibe os jogos de todas as categorias
        myExportedResourcesList = ExportedResource.findAllByTypeAndOwnerAndNameIlike('public', user, "%${params.text}%", params)
        maxInstances = ExportedResource.findAllByTypeAndOwnerAndNameIlike('public', user, "%${params.text}%").size()
    }
    else{
        Category c = Category.findById(params.category)
        myExportedResourcesList = []
        maxInstances = 0
      for (r in Resource.findAllByCategory(c)) {
            // get all resources belong
            myExportedResourcesList.addAll(
                    ExportedResource.findAllByTypeAndResourceAndOwnerAndNameIlike('public', r, user, "%${params.text}%", params))
            maxInstances += ExportedResource.countByTypeAndResourceAndOwnerAndNameIlike('public', r, user, "%${params.text}%")
        }
    }
    model.publicExportedResourcesList = myExportedResourcesList
    model.pageCount = Math.ceil(maxInstances / params.max) as int
    model.currentPage = (params.offset + threshold) / threshold
    model.hasNextPage = params.offset + threshold < model.instanceCount
    model.hasPreviousPage = params.offset > 0
    model.page = 'myGames'
    log.debug("maxInstances final: "+maxInstances)
    render view: "_customizedGameCard", model:model
}
```

View _customizedGameCard

```
<g:external dir="css" file="card.css" />

<main class="cardGames">
    <div class="row">
        <g:if test="${publicExportedResourcesList.size() > 0}">
            <g:each in="${publicExportedResourcesList}" var="instance">

                <div id="card${instance.id}" data-instance_id="${instance.id}" class="col l2 m4 s6 fullCard">
                    <div class="card hoverable">

                        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-light">
                            <img alt="${instance.name}" class="activator" src="/published/${instance.processId}/banner.png">
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-content">
                            <span class="card-title flow-text grey-text text-darken-4 activator valign-wrapper truncate no-padding"
                                  data-category="${instance.resource.category.id}" title="${instance.name}">
                                <p class="no-margin truncate">${instance.name}</p>
                                <i class="material-icons right remar-orange-text">more_vert</i>
                            </span>

                            <div class="divider"></div>

                            <span>${instance.resource.category.name}</span>
                            <span class="truncate">
                                <g:message code="exportedResource.label.madeBy" default="Feito por:"/>
                                <a href="#!" class="user-profile" id="user-id-${instance.owner.id}">
                                    ${instance.owner.username}
                                </a>
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <i class="fa fa-globe tooltipped" data-tooltip="Web"></i>
                                <g:if test="${instance.resource.android}">
                                    <i class="fa fa-android tooltipped" data-tooltip="Android"></i>
                                </g:if>
                                <g:if test="${instance.resource.desktop}">
                                    <i class="fa fa-windows tooltipped" data-tooltip="Windows"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-linux tooltipped" data-tooltip="Linux"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-apple tooltipped" data-tooltip="Mac"></i>
                                </g:if>
                                <g:if test="${instance.resource.moodle}">
                                    <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i>
                                </g:if>
                            </span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-reveal col s12">
                            <div class="row no-margin">
                                <div class="col s6 no-padding">
                                    <h6 class="grey-text text-darken-4 no-margin">
                                        <g:message code="exportedResource.label.play" default="Jogar"/>
                                    </h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col s6 no-padding">
                                    <div class="row no-margin card-title valign-wrapper right-align">
                                        <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col s6 m4 l3">
                                    <a target="_blank" href="/published/${instance.processId}/web" class="tooltipped"
                                       data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Web">
                                        <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <g:if test="${instance.resource.desktop}">
                                    <div class="col s6 m4 l3">
                                        <a target="_blank" href="/published/${instance.processId}/desktop/${instance.resource.uri}-linux.zip" class="tooltipped"
                                           data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Linux">
                                            <i class="fa fa-linux"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col s6 m4 l3">
                                        <a target="_blank" href="/published/${instance.processId}/desktop/${instance.resource.uri}-windows.zip" class="tooltipped"
                                           data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Windows">
                                            <i class="fa fa-windows"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col s6 m4 l3">
                                        <a target="_blank" href="/published/${instance.processId}/desktop/${instance.resource.uri}-mac.zip" class="tooltipped"
                                           data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Mac">
                                            <i class="fa fa-apple"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </g:if>
                                <div class="col s6 m4 l3">
                                    <g:if test="${instance.resource.android}">
                                        <a target="_blank" href="/published/${instance.processId}/mobile/${instance.resource.uri}-android.zip" class="tooltipped"
                                           data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Android">
                                            <i class="fa fa-android"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </g:if>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col s6 m4 l3">
                                    <g:if test="${instance.resource.moodle}">
                                        <a target="_blank" class="tooltipped"
                                           data-position="right" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Disponível no Moodle">
                                            <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </g:if>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="divider"></div>
                            <br/>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col s6 m4 l3">
                                    <a href="/exported-resource/info/${instance.id}" class="tooltipped"
                                       data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Mais informações">
                                        <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <g:if test="${!(mode == 'public')}">
                                    <g:if test="${instance.resource.shareable}">
                                        <div class="col s6 m4 l3">
                                            <a href="#modal-group" class="tooltipped compartilhaModal"
                                               data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Compartilhar para grupos">
                                                <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </g:if>
                                    <g:else>
                                        <div class="col s6 m4 l3">
                                            <div class="tooltipped"
                                                 data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Sem compartilharmento para grupos">
                                                <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </g:else>
                                    <div class="col s6 m4 l3 ">
                                        <a href="#modal-delete-exported-resource" class="tooltipped modal-trigger deleteExportedResource"
                                           data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Excluir">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </g:if>
                            </div>

                            <div class="divider"></div>
                            <br/>

                            <div class="license-info license-image-only center-align" data-license="${instance.license}"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </g:each>
        </g:if>

        %{--Modal for groups--}%
        <div id="modal-group" class="modal remar-modal shareModal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                %{--Preenchido pelo javascript--}%
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a class="modal-action modal-close btn waves-effect waves-light remar-orange" type="submit" name="action">Fechar</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        %{--Modal for delete--}%
        <div class="modal-wrapper-50">
            <div id="modal-delete-exported-resource" class="modal remar-modal">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <h4><g:message code="exportedResource.label.deleteCustomizingGame" default="Excluir Jogo em Customização"/></h4>

                    <p><g:message code="exportedResource.label.confirmAction" default="Tem certeza que deseja realizar esta ação?"/></p>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a id="confirmDeleteExpResource" class="modal-action modal-close btn waves-effect waves-light remar-orange">Sim</a>
                    <a class="modal-action modal-close btn waves-effect waves-light remar-orange">Não</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <g:applyLayout name="pagination"/>
    <g:if test='${page == 'myGames'}'>
    <g:javascript src="remar/utility/utility-my-game.js"/>
  </g:if>
  <g:else>
    <g:javascript src="remar/utility/utility-public-game.js"/>
  </g:else>
    <g:javascript src="remar/licenseShow.js"/>
    <g:javascript src="remar/resource.actions.js"/>
</main>
```

Função no utility_my_games.js

```
$(select).change(function(){
        var catSelected = $(select).val();
        var text = $("#search").val();

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('category', catSelected);
        formData.append('text', text);
        console.log("Ha "+ $(this).val());
        console.log("formData categories: "+ formData.getAll('category'));
        $.ajax({
            url: "/exported-resource/searchMyGames",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (response) {
                $(".cardGames").remove();
                $("#showCards").append(response);
                $(".next-page").each(function() {
                    $(this).on("click",listerNextPage)
                });
                addMaterializeDepedences();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Tente trocando o `$(".next-page").each(function() {
                    $(this).on("click",listerNextPage)
                });` por apenas `$(".next-page").on("click", listerNextPage)`... esse `each` me parece desnecessário.

Comment: Fiz isso, mas não fez diferença referente ao problema que estou tendo :/ Porém, percebi que a consulta se repete na potência de 2 do número de chamadas que fiz... por exemplo, na segunda chamada acontece 4 repetições, já na terceira, 8... Você já se deparou com isso?

Comment: Remova os eventos anteriores utilizando o método off() do jquery. Algo como: $(this).off().on("click",listerNextPage)